# Java - Execute a line(s) of code in main method only once.

Tags: java, serversocket

I am trying to implement a server - client model. Originally I had a java program scheduled via Windows scheduler to run once a day to perform an activity. I am trying to modify this by having the program act as a server, i.e. accept user input on demand from a client and perform the same activity as before. So essentially I needed the java program to be listening on some IP & port all the time to perform the on-demand functionality while also run via Windows scheduler once a day. I have been able to achieve most of the requirements however stuck on a final hurdle - I need the thread.start() in my main method to be called only once during first start up and not be called each time the Windows scheduler invokes the program as it understandably creates a JVM Bind Error.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 //some code

//***********************************************************************


// The 2 lines below enables the server to bind and listen to a particular IP & port. 
Thread t = new Thread(XXX);
t.start();

//***********************************************************************


// Basically the code within "***" should not be executed when the main method gets called via Windows scheduler every 24 hours. Only originalMethodCalled() should be executed. 

originalMethodCalled();


}//main method
```

Any suggestions to achieve this seemingly simple activity would be much appreciated.

Comment: If the program now is a server that is always on, why do you schedule it every day? Why don't you instead schedule a client program that connects to the server and send it a command?

Comment: Pass in a command-line argument, e.g. `-start`. Or, if you otherwise hardcoded the IP and Port, use `-ip` and `-port`.

Comment: To follow up on comment by @JBNizet, if the program is already running, it can start a timer to do something at a later (scheduled) time. Alternatively, the scheduled job can run a client program that simply sends a message to the server program, basically saying: Do it now.

Comment: @JB Nizet - Program being called via Windows Scheduler on a 24 hour basis is a requirement that can't be altered. @ Andreas, Thanks but I got all that stuff done. Basically I need a way to ensure the code within ** in my example gets called once and not each time the main method gets called via Schedular.

Comment: Then make it act as a client: if it can connect to the server, then send the command to the server (or execute it behind its back), and if it can't connect, then start the server and execute the task.

Comment: I'm curious?!  Aren't you just creating new processes during each Scheduler run?  I mean if you run the Windows Scheduler on 04/04/2016 and it creates pid=1001.  24 hours later, the Windows Scheduler runs again on 04/05/2016 and it creates a new process/new pid...the pid=1001 is still running isn't it?